# Mapping $G$ into its group algebra as left multiplication. Continuous?

Tags: representation-theory, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis, lp-spaces, locally-compact-groups

I am reading an appendix on Group algebras which contains the following Proposition which I am trying to prove:

**Proposition:** Let $G$ be a locally compact group, with $\zeta\in L^{p}(G)$ fixed.  Define $L_{x}\in L^{p}(G)$ by $L_{x}(\zeta)[\lambda] = \zeta(x\lambda)$.  The map
$$G\mapsto L^{p}(G), x\mapsto L_{x}(\zeta)$$
is continuous.

**My Proof Attempt:**

It was not obvious to me that this map is well-defined; but I think I have verified it below.  Can someone check my logic and confirm I am using the notation correctly?  My measure theory background always leaves me feeling uneasy when abstract measure space show up.

Let $\mu$ denote the left Haar measure for $G$.

$\begin{align*}
\int_{G}|L_{x}(\zeta)|^{p}d\mu &= \int_{G}|\zeta(xy)|^{p}\mu(dy)\\
 &= \int_{G}|\zeta(y)|^{p}\mu(x\cdot dy)\text{, (transformation property)}\\
 &= \int_{G}|\zeta(y)|^{p}\mu(dy)\text{, (by Left }G\text{-invariance)}\\
 &= \|\zeta\|_{p}^{p} <\infty\text{, because }\zeta\in L^{p}(G)
\end{align*}$

Therefore $L_{x}(\zeta)\in L^{p}(G)$, so the map is well-defined.

Now to show the map is continuous, it suffices by $G$-invariance of $\mu$ to show that whenever $x_{\alpha}\to 1$, we have $\|L_{x_{\alpha}}(\zeta) - \zeta\|_{p}\to 0$.

I'm stuck here though, as I have no idea how to estimate $\int_{G}|\zeta(x_{\alpha}y) - \zeta(y)|^{p}d\mu$.  What is the trick?

Comment: Can you do it for the characteristic function of an open set? Notice that is enough, for they span $L^p$.

Comment: Yes I think I can, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Alternatively, show that the action of $G$ on $C_c(G)$ is continuous with respect to the sup-norm since functions in $C_c(G)$ are uniformly continuous. Then use that $C_c(G)$ is dense in $L^p$ for $p \lt \infty$. A more detailed outline is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141198/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.  I'll try that approach.