# Why are Haar measures finite on compact sets?

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

I'm working through the answer by t.b. to another user's question here:

[A net version of dominated convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141198/a-net-version-of-dominated-convergence)

because I am trying to work through a related problem and I think it will be illuminating.

From step two, "Then $KK'$ is compact and thus has finite Haar measure."

why is this true?

---

$\bf{\text{My attempt so far}}$:

Let $\mu$ be a left Haar measure on a locally compact group $G$.  Then  $\mu$ is non-zero, regular, and left $G$-invariant.  Let $K\subset G$ be compact.

$\color{red}{(!)}$ If I could construct set $U$ with the properties:

(i) $1\in U$

(ii) $0 < \mu(U) < \infty$

(iii) $U$ is open.

Then I could cover $K$ with $\{xU : x\in K\}$ and choose finitely many $k_{1}, ... , k_{n}\in K$ such that $K\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}xU$ which forces $\mu(K)\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\mu(xU) = n\mu(U) < \infty$.

I don't know how to construct such a $U$, though it seems innocent enough to ask for.

Does such a $U$ exist? or is the proof much more difficult?

Comment: What is your definition of a Haar measure? As far as I know, they are always defined to be finite on compact sets. In other words, a Haar measure $\mu$ is a Borel measure that is positive on open sets, left-invariant, regular, and finite on compact sets.

Comment: The definition I read was that it is non-zero, regular and left-invariant.

Comment: I checked here (which I should have done in the first place I guess) which agrees it must be finite on compact sets.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Haar measure is finite on compact sets by definition: A Borel measure $\mu$ on a topological group $G$ is a (left) Haar measure if

1. $\mu$ is regular.
2. $\mu$ is left-invariant, *i.e.* $\mu(xU) = \mu(U)$ for any measurable $U \subset G$.
3. $\mu(U) > 0$ for all $U \subset G$ open.
4. $\mu(K) < \infty$ for all $K \subset H$ compact.

Comment: Possible to reduce $4$th property from $3$rd property?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 6):

It is in fact possible to deduce a Haar measure is finite on compact sets from the rest of the axioms, if you assume there is *some* nonempty subset of finite measure.

Let $A\subseteq G$ such that $\mu(A)<\infty$. By regularity there is some open set $U\supseteq A$ such that $\mu(U)\leqslant\mu(A)+\varepsilon<\infty$ (for every $\varepsilon>0$, say $\varepsilon=1$). Since $U$ is open we also have $\mu(U)>0$. Now, pick some $u_0\in U$ and let $V:=u_0^{-1}U$; by left invariance $\mu(V)=\mu(U)$. We conclude that $V$ is open, $1\in V$ and $0<\mu(V)<\infty$.

The rest you've already showed: if $K$ is compact, then $\{kV\}_{k\in K}$ is an open cover of $K$, and hence there are $k_1,...,k_n$ such that $K\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n k_iV$, and therefore $\mu(K)\leqslant n\cdot \mu(V)<\infty$.

It is not clear to me why some people put this in the definition of a Haar measure. Incidentally, it is also not necessary to assume a Haar measure is positive on open sets if you assume it is non-zero: if you had some open set $V\subseteq G$ such that $\mu(V)=0$, then clearly you'd have that $\mu(K)=0$ for every compact $K$, which means by regularity that $\mu(G)=0$.

Comment: I'd never thought that finiteness on compacts was part of the definition, either. In general, unless a non-negative regular Borel measure gives some _point_  infinite measure, your argument shows that every point has an open nbd with finite measure, and then compacts must have finite measure.

Comment: You're right, you don't even need to assume $G$ is a group if you assume no point has infinite measure. This is a good point... And yet somehow I often saw this in the definition of a Haar measure. Very weird.

Comment: In fact, I needed to assume no point has infinite measure as well (which in the case of groups is the same as assuming there is some noempty set which is of finite measure).

Comment: Heh. II was considering saying  that the finiteness on a sets had better follow from the definition, because otherwise setting $\mu(E)=\infty$ for all nonemptty $E$ gives a counterexample. Wasn't sure I wanted to point this out, since it's sort of a lame boring counterexample. But heh, it's the _only_ counterexample - very good.'

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich hehe, yap, it's amusing.