# Stuck in integration problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Could someone give me some hint or show me how to calculate this integration? $$\huge{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty}z^2e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\ dz$$Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had never seen the use of such huge fonts on MSE!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the function $I(a)$ be the integral given by

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-az^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\end{align}$$

Then, note that $I'(1/2)$ is

$$\begin{align}
I'(1/2)&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2e^{-\frac12 z^2}\,dz\\\\
&=-\sqrt{2\pi}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2e^{-\frac12 z^2}\,dz=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

---

> **NOTE:  Legitimacy of Differentiating Under the Integral Sign**

Here, we legitimize the differentiation under the integral.  First, we form the difference quotient

$$\frac{I(a+h)-I(a)}{h}=2\int_0^\infty \left(-z^2e^{-az^2}\right)\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\,dz$$

---

**Case 1: $h>0$**

For $h>0$, we have

$$\left|\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\right|\le 1$$

Therefore, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{I(a+h)-I(a)}{h}&=2\int_0^\infty \left(-z^2e^{-az^2}\right)\lim_{h\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\right)\,dz\\\\
&=-2\int_0^\infty (-z^2e^{-az^2})\,dz
\end{align}$$

---

**Case 2: $h<0$**

For $h<0$, we first split the integral of interest as

$$\frac{I(a+h)-I(a)}{h}=\int_0^{1\sqrt{|h|}} \left(-z^2e^{-az^2}\right)\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\,dz+\int_{1/\sqrt{|h|}}^\infty \left(-z^2e^{-az^2}\right)\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\,dz$$

For $z<1\sqrt{|h|}$, $\left|\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\right|\le e-1$ while for $z>1\sqrt{|h|}$ and $|h|<a/2$, $\left|\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\right|\le e^{\frac a2 z^2}$.  Then, since

$$\left|\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\right|\le g(z)=\begin{cases}e-1&,z<1\sqrt{|h|}\\\\e^{\frac a2 z^2}&,z>1/\sqrt{|h|}\end{cases}$$

with $\int_0^\infty g(z)(-z^2e^{-az^2})\,dz<\infty$

the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{I(a+h)-I(a)}{h}&=2\int_0^\infty \left(-z^2e^{-az^2}\right)\lim_{h\to 0^-}\left(\frac{1-e^{-hz^2}}{hz^2}\right)\,dz\\\\
&=-2\int_0^\infty (-z^2e^{-az^2})\,dz
\end{align}$$
-______________________________

> Inasmuch as the limits from right-hand and left-hand sides are equal, then
>
> $$I'(a)=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2e^{-az^2}\,dz$$

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: The integral is $\sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: @VivekKaushik I've edited

Comment: -1. Differentiating under an improper integral implies exchanging three limits. Doing so without justification as if it was trivial is bad form, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I spend countless hours trolling the site and downvoting answers.

Comment: @MartinArgerami OK.  Now, that was funny!

Comment: Seriously, I think it is a bad answer if you don't justify it. It might be obvious to you that dominated convergence works; but in a question with no *measure theory* tag, I don't think it is reasonable to expect the OP to have a working knowledge of dominated convergence. And, more importantly, I think we shouldn't encourage "happy-go-lucky" math; here differentiation under the integral works, but it doesn't work all the time. It's like those cases where people apply L'Hôpital without caring to see if the conditions for it are satisfied.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I've taken your suggestion seriously and added an appendix in which I show the legitimacy of differentiating under the integral.  I do appreciate your suggestion - only wish you would have given me a chance to amend before the down vote.  -Mark

Comment: Nice work (by the way, downvotes can be reversed, and I already did). Still, I wouldn't call that "straightforward..." ;)  One minor caveat, is that dominated convergence [requires sequences](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/141276/22857). This is not a big deal here, because if all sequential limits of Newton quotients converge to the same value, then the Newton quotient will converge to that value.. But, again, a "not-straightforward" part of the argument.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Martin, much appreciative!  And yes, it isn't as straightforward as I had thought when originally posting.  -Mark

Answer (score 7):

Try integration by parts, differentiating $z$ and integrating $ze^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$. You'll need the fact that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\;dz=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Comment: That helps!!! Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

Consider 
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$
$$I^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2y^2e^{\frac{-x^2-y^2}{2}}dydx$$

Convert to polar $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$ so that $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}=r$

The double integral becomes: 
$$I^2=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}r^5(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^2e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}drd\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^2\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}r^5e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}dr\right)d\theta$$

For the inner integral use integration by parts $u=r^4,dv=re^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}dr$. You will have to do this repeatedly to get the antiderivative. Then evaluate the antiderivative at the endpoints to get $8$ for the inner integral.

Now we have:
$$I^2=\int_{0}^{2\pi}8(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^2 d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}2(\sin(2\theta))^2 d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}1-\cos(4\theta) d\theta=2\pi$$

So $$I=\sqrt{2\pi}$$